# Save Bitmap in costume directory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

i have bitmap file and i wan't to save it in costume directory or custom file like
fashtion_project/images/pic1.png.
All code that i tried was deprecated on android 10 or and android Pie .
i need code to convert bitmap to file and save it in custom file

i tried this code and it not work in all devices

```java
  void addImageToGallery(Bitmap bmp, Context context) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "outfit");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/Shop/");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);

        Uri collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        Uri imageUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(collection, values);

        if (imageUri != null) {
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                toastError();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            values.clear();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
            context.getContentResolver().update(imageUri, values, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            toastError();
        }

    }
```

and before that i checked if external storage is available for read and write
but it not working in all devices

```java
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

what can i do to fix these problem

Comment: Have you added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in  manifest.xml?

Comment: yes i added  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  in the manifest